# HMS Location Kit - Latitude,Longitude comes to 0 problem

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I try to get location information on the Virtual Device in the App Gallery console, but the location information comes to zero, what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes data problems occur in the location kit when taking location via virtual device. If you try it with a real device, you'll see that the problem is gone. :)